# How to launch karma Chrome in background

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, automated-tests, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I want to run karma chrome launcher in background because i am generating html tests and coverage reports which means i don't need a visual browser appearing everytime i run a test.

Here is my karma config file

```
plugins : [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-browserify',
      'karma-jasmine-jquery',
      'karma-html-reporter',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-es6-shim'
    ],
...
customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_without_security: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--disable-web-security']
      }
    }
...

// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome', 'Chrome_without_security' ]
```

i tried the `'--no-startup-window'` flag but it did not work

any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/27

Comment: i've already tried that solution bit it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I believe 'ChromeHeadless' is what you need.